# How to enable/disable trigger in procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two databases (`firstDB` and `secondDB`) on MS SQL server.
There is procedure `[dbo].[MaintaineIndexes]` in `firstDB` and `DatabaseEventsTrigger` in `secondDB`.

I want to disable `secondDB.DatabaseEventsTrigger` when I am running `[dbo].[MaintaineIndexes]`.

So I tried:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MaintaineIndexes] 
AS
BEGIN
DISABLE TRIGGER DatabaseEventsTrigger ON secondDB; 
...
ENABLE TRIGGER DatabaseEventsTrigger ON secondDB;
END;
```

When I'm running procedure I'm getting error message: "Cannot find the object "secondDB" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.";

Ok, then I tryed:

```
DISABLE TRIGGER DatabaseEventsTrigger ON ALL SERVER;
```

- same error.

Disabling trigger only working with this commands:

```
USE [secondDB]
GO
DISABLE TRIGGER DatabaseEventsTrigger ON DATABASE;
```

But we can't use `USE` in procedures! So, how to enable/disable triggers in my situation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use Dynamic SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MaintaineIndexes] 
AS
BEGIN
   EXEC('DISABLE TRIGGER DatabaseEventsTrigger ON secondDB'); 
   ...
   EXEC('ENABLE TRIGGER DatabaseEventsTrigger ON secondDB');
END;
```

OR:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MaintaineIndexes] 
AS
BEGIN
   EXEC('USE [secondDB]; DISABLE TRIGGER DatabaseEventsTrigger ON DATABASE;'); 
   ...
   EXEC('USE [secondDB]; ENABLE TRIGGER DatabaseEventsTrigger ON DATABASE;'); 
END;
```

Comment: Is Dynamic SQL preferable to a simple `ALTER TABLE` statement as in my answer? Or is it just another way to accomplish the same?

Comment: @HoneyBadger, it seems the question is a DDL trigger, not DML trigger (`disabled via ALTER TABLE`).

Comment: @HoneyBadger Simply in stored procedure you cannot use this syntax, using EXEC create new context and then you can use it.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks, I guess I responded without thinking too much :P