# Enable Disable Trigger vis stored procedure SQL Server 2012 behaviour

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

My question is simple: how to enable and disable triggers in a stored procedure.

I now have the solution thanks to the good old SO community.  BUT!

[In This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352415/how-to-enable-disable-trigger-in-procedure)

Specifically what is the behaviour and why does this below not work in updating stored procedures?

```
BEGIN
GO
DISABLE TRIGGER DatabaseEventsTrigger ON DB; 
...
GO
ENABLE TRIGGER DatabaseEventsTrigger ON DB;
END;
```

I have also observed that this actually enables and disables the trigger in real time while I am simply updating a stored procedure and not executing it. Then does not save the changes made to the procedure.

Could someone please explain this behaviour?

EDIT:

What I am updating my stored procedure with is this but instead of `Command(s) completed successfully.` in the results window I get `(x) rows affected`

```
BEGIN
GO
DISABLE TRIGGER DatabaseEventsTrigger ON DB; 
go
--Run my update here where my conditions are met.
GO
ENABLE TRIGGER DatabaseEventsTrigger ON DB;
go
END;
```

I then refreshed my table trigger out of curiosity when I rem'd out the enable part of the query.  I found it was disabled.  The update action in my stored procedure actually executed this piece of code.

To me this was strange.  I really ant to further understand why....

Comment: Whether this is in a stored procedure or not this is not valid syntax. `GO` is the batch separator in SSMS and `BEGIN/END` does not traverse batches. So in your first batch you have `BEGIN` with no END, your second batch is fine, and your third batch has `END` with no `BEGIN`. A stored procedure must be a single batch, so you cannot place multiple batches in a single stored procedure, the only way to do this is to use dynamic SQL, which will execute as its own batch.

Comment: Thank you @GarethD for making me aware of that.  Are you able to explain why it would actually run the command while I am simply hitting F5 after update the sproc?

Comment: I couldn't tell you without seeing exactly what you are running, if you just ran the script you have posted (after removing ...) you should get 3 errors `Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'`, `Cannot find the object "DB" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.`, and `Incorrect syntax new ';'`

Comment: What might be of help is the section in Aaron Bertrand's [stored procedure "best practices" checklist](https://sqlblog.org/2008/10/30/my-stored-procedure-best-practices-checklist) titled "Using BEGIN / END liberally", this can explain why a stored procedure may appear to be updated using `GO`, but the effects aren't as you may thing.

Comment: Thanks again @GarethD.  I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `GO` in the code in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you can use something like this

`EXEC('ENABLE TRIGGER [SchemaName].[TriggerName] ON [SchemaName].[TableName]');`

inside SP code