# Disabling trigger only for specific oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, triggers, procedure

We have a requirement to disable a trigger only for a specific procedure run in ORACLE.

We have Table A and Table B.

The trigger is designed to insert into Table B for each insert or update of Table A.

The procedure makes entries to Table A.

[How to enable/disable trigger in procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352415/how-to-enable-disable-trigger-in-procedure)

The above link explains how to enable and disable the trigger during the procedure.

But my requirement is during this procedure run, if there are other inserts to Table A, then the trigger should run as expected.

Is this possible? Please help on how to achieve the same if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO` and `SYS_CONTEXT` to set any parameter in your procedure and then check for that parameter in the `TRIGGER` to see if you should take any action in the trigger or not as follows:

**Table description:**

```
SQL> DESC AA;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL1                                      NOT NULL NUMBER

SQL>
```

**Trigger code:**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AA_TRG BEFORE
  2  INSERT OR UPDATE ON AA
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5  IF SYS_CONTEXT(
  6  'USERENV',
  7  'ACTION'
  8  ) = 'DISABLE_TRIGGER' THEN
  9  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TRIGGER DISABLED');
 10  ELSE
 11  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TRIGGER ENABLED');
 12  END IF;
 13
 14  DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_ACTION(ACTION_NAME => NULL);
 15  END;
 16  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

**Disabled trigger procedure code:**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AA_DISABLED_TRIGGER_PROC AS
  2  BEGIN
  3  DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_ACTION(ACTION_NAME => 'DISABLE_TRIGGER');
  4  INSERT INTO AA VALUES ( 3 );
  5
  6  ROLLBACK;
  7  END;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

**Enabled trigger procedure code:**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AA_ENABLED_TRIGGER_PROC AS
  2  BEGIN
  3  INSERT INTO AA VALUES ( 3 );
  4
  5  ROLLBACK;
  6  END;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

**Calling the procedures:**

```
SQL>
SQL> SET SERVEROUT ON
SQL> BEGIN
  2  AA_ENABLED_TRIGGER_PROC;
  3  END;
  4  /
TRIGGER ENABLED

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> SET SERVEROUT ON
SQL> BEGIN
  2  AA_DISABLED_TRIGGER_PROC;
  3  END;
  4  /
TRIGGER DISABLED

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> SET SERVEROUT ON
SQL> BEGIN
  2  AA_ENABLED_TRIGGER_PROC;
  3  END;
  4  /
TRIGGER ENABLED

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details. Will check and revert back

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. If trigger is disabled, then it is *disabled* and won't work.

But, if you alter the table and add a column which says who is inserting rows into it, then you could use trigger's `WHEN` clause to distinguish this procedure from other *inserters* and either fire the trigger or not. It means, of course, that trigger remains enabled all the time.